# Refinery-cms sub uri

Tags: uri, refinerycms

I'm trying to set up refinery cms to work in a apache/passenger with a sub uri. But when i access the site and admin area, i get a strange behavior (Images aren't loaded correctly, pages can't be edited, etc.)

I was wondering if sub uri are simply not supported or if there is some sort of workaround available

(running rails 3.0.3 and refinery 0.9.9)

The reason i want to do this is to have the capability of hosting multiple refinery based sites on the same server/ip port 80.. simply by putting them each on a different sub uri.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a really old question... I am trying to do the same, and found this question.

I've installed Rails 3.0.11, along with refinerycms 1.0.9, and some images are broken (on Apache/Passenger)..  digging a little deeper I found that the locations of all the images ref'd in CSS are hard-coded, I find this highly annoying.. but it is what it is. Apparently they're working to get the cms working with the asset pipeline, which would fix these issues.

In the meanwhile, you can override them in your applications public folder just fine; you'll find most of the css in the refinery-core gem.. 
For instance do: 
`rake refinery:override stylesheet=refinery/refinery`
and then open the override file it installed and then do a find-replace of /images/ with //images/  ..That worked for me.

ETA: Don't forget to delete the public/refinery/cache folder contents after making changes.